# Having/Where clause not working for Haversine Formula using Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, haversine

Here is my table named "test" -
Check the snapshot here **[test](http://i.gyazo.com/12e579202193d28b4620605aef3db4aa.png)**

And then my row items: here - **[rowitems](http://gyazo.com/e49d5058326a1b5f204dcb9b8adcb4d9.png)**

I'm using the haversine formula, he is my query

```
  SELECT *, ( 3960 * acos( cos( radians( 33.650800 ) ) *
  cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians(  Longitude  ) - radians( -117.891729 ) ) +
  sin( radians( 33.650800 ) ) * sin( radians(  Latitude  ) ) ) ) AS Distance 
  FROM test
```

For some reason the `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause is not working with `Distance`.

It works with `Latitude` or `Longitude`.

But when I try to do `WHERE Distance < 10 or HAVING Distance < 10`. It says `Distance is an invalid column name`.

I need to be able to do this, and make a query using `Distance`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I encourage you to read this:  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/sql-server-zipcode-latitude-longitude-pr/ In this blog, I show some clever ways to speed up the execution of proximity searches.  This is especially true if your table has many rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use calculated fields on a where or having clause. Create a view or use a subquery

Try this:

```
select * FROM (SELECT *, ( 3960 * acos( cos( radians( 33.650800 ) ) *
cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians(  Longitude  ) - radians( -117.891729 ) ) +
sin( radians( 33.650800 ) ) * sin( radians(  Latitude  ) ) ) ) AS Distance 
FROM test) as T WHERE T.Distance < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your query into a subquery, or a view, or a CTE (common table expression).

Here is an example for your task with a CTE:

```
WITH cte_test (Name, Latitude, Longitude, Distance)
AS 
(
    SELECT Name, Latitude, Longitude, 
         3960 * acos(cos(radians(33.650800)) 
         * cos(radians( Latitude ) )  
         * cos( radians(  Longitude  ) - radians( -117.891729 ) ) 
         + sin( radians( 33.650800 ) ) * sin( radians(  Latitude  ) ) ) ) 
         AS Distance 
    FROM test
)
SELECT * from cte_test where Distance < 10 ;
```

A CTE is a kind of "temporary view". It is also a powerful instrument which can also be used for creating recursive queries.