# Filter latitude and longitude records based on for given latitude and longitude for given n kilometre

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-server-2005, latitude-longitude

I have latitude and longitude stored in a table and I want to *filter* the records that are in *n kilo meter radius* from the *given latitude and longitude.*

I searched sql-server management studio system functions But it is not having any.

any valuable suggestions on how do I go about solving this issue would be helpful..

Note:

I am looking for a solution that uses just plain-sql coupled with forumlas so that it can be used in other db such as sqlite too.

Edit:

This question is different from [sqlite-getting-nearest-locations-with-latitude-and-longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695224/sqlite-getting-nearest-locations-with-latitude-and-longitude) because its scope is completely limited usage of only sql statements i.e no usage of java as in the question

Comment: There's a good article on this topic here: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/ it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211163/having-where-clause-not-working-for-haversine-formula-using-microsoft-sql

Comment: Thanks..If you could give me a sql statements that simply takes two parameters (latitude,longitude and distance) it would be a helpful lot

Comment: It sounds like you want a stored procedure or a function. it should be easy enough to rewrite to code in the articles I linked as functions or procs.

Comment: @CL - My question is different bcuz its scope is limited to sql.But the question that is linked has scope with java and sql too.Hope you understand and open the question so that I can get the answer ..

Comment: That question shows what is possible in SQL (especially when it's limited as in SQLite), and what has to be done in your programming language.

Comment: @CL. - my question is not limited to Sqlite rather it covers up-to sql-server.I think you will change your mind